# Error: non-public domain when proxying google oauth redirect URI to nginx upstream server

Tags: docker, express, nginx, oauth-2.0

I'm using google oauth2 for authentication on a nodejs/react application that is running on docker. I have an nginx server that listens for incoming traffic and proxys requests to either the express or react upstream servers. When the google redirect URI is proxy'd to the express server, I get a non-public domains not allowed error. For development purposes, is it possible to use google oauth2 with the docker machine ip?

I've tried using the xip.io solution stated in other similar questions.

My default.conf for nginx:

```
upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

...

server {
  listen 80;

...

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }

  location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

The error generated:
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://api/auth/google/callback

Comment: @Jacobs were you able to find a solution to this?